# How does WatcherThread invoke JVM monitoring routines?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

"VM Periodic Task Thread"

> Aka the "WatcherThread". This is a VM thread that performs periodic
> tasks, e.g., updating performance counters.

see [link](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2012-April/005667.html)

> Periodic task scheduling of threads, it was founded by WatcherThread, is a singleton object.
>
> The thread in JVM more frequently used, For example, the running status of the memory monitoring, JVM monitoring regularly. And we often need to perform some `jstat` this command for the GC case.
>
> As follows: `jstat -gcutil 234832507` making this command tells the JVM in the console to print PID: GC 23483, An interval of 250 msec print a, A total of over 7 prints.

see [link](http://www.programering.com/a/MDM3MjNwATU.html)

This is what I find in the JVM source code.

I think when the "VM Periodic Task Thread"(WatcherThread) starts, it should perform "run" function.
The only thing I notice is that it spins in the while loop,
but how does WatcherThread invoke JVM monitoring routines, like `jstat`?
Where is the sub-routine of `jstat` in this while loop?
I am curious how WatcherThread updates performance counters and things like that.

```
void WatcherThread::run() {
  assert(this == watcher_thread(), "just checking");

  this->record_stack_base_and_size();
  this->set_native_thread_name(this->name());
  this->set_active_handles(JNIHandleBlock::allocate_block());

  while (true) {
    assert(watcher_thread() == Thread::current(), "thread consistency check");
    assert(watcher_thread() == this, "thread consistency check");

    // Calculate how long it'll be until the next PeriodicTask work
    // should be done, and sleep that amount of time.
    int time_waited = sleep();  // return 50

    if (is_error_reported()) {
      // A fatal error has happened, the error handler(VMError::report_and_die)
      // should abort JVM after creating an error log file. However in some
      // rare cases, the error handler itself might deadlock. Here we try to
      // kill JVM if the fatal error handler fails to abort in 2 minutes.
      //
      // This code is in WatcherThread because WatcherThread wakes up
      // periodically so the fatal error handler doesn't need to do anything;
      // also because the WatcherThread is less likely to crash than other
      // threads.

      for (;;) {
        if (!ShowMessageBoxOnError
            && (OnError == NULL || OnError[0] == '\0')
            && Arguments::abort_hook() == NULL) {
          os::sleep(this, (jlong)ErrorLogTimeout * 1000, false); // in seconds
          fdStream err(defaultStream::output_fd());
          err.print_raw_cr("# [ timer expired, abort... ]");
          // skip atexit/vm_exit/vm_abort hooks
          os::die();
        }

        // Wake up 5 seconds later, the fatal handler may reset OnError or
        // ShowMessageBoxOnError when it is ready to abort.
        os::sleep(this, 5 * 1000, false);
      }
    }

    if (_should_terminate) {
      // check for termination before posting the next tick
      break;
    }

    PeriodicTask::real_time_tick(time_waited);
  }

  // Signal that it is terminated
  {
    MutexLockerEx mu(Terminator_lock, Mutex::_no_safepoint_check_flag);
    _watcher_thread = NULL;
    Terminator_lock->notify();
  }
}
```

Comment: `jstat` is a command line tool. I’m quiet sure that the JVM does not call external command line tools. This loop obviously invokes `PeriodicTask::real_time_tick` in each regular iteration. Besides that, you cited a block of text without any reference to its source. Who has written that in what context?

Comment: @Holger I have added reference links. What I find in the `PeriodicTask::real_time_tick` is that it does some accounting information about timers. The most noticeable one is `_tasks[index]->execute_if_pending(delay_time)`. It seems to do some real jobs in `task()`. Got it! I think it finally invokes `StatSamplerTask::task` if doing a sample.

Comment: Did you really consider the second source for getting viable information? I’m still wondering what the difference between “Making making making making” and “Making making making” is and whether the original text made more sense before that broken translation…

Comment: @Holger  This is strange for me too at the first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously JVM does not call `jstat` or other external utilities.

You are probably looking for [`StatSampler::collect_sample`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a9b412abe617/src/share/vm/runtime/statSampler.cpp#l158):

```
/*
 * the collect_sample() method is the method invoked by the
 * WatcherThread via the PeriodicTask::task() method. This method
 * is responsible for collecting data samples from sampled
 * PerfData instances every PerfDataSamplingInterval milliseconds.
 * It is also responsible for logging the requested set of
 * PerfData instances every _sample_count milliseconds. While
 * logging data, it will output a column header after every _print_header
 * rows of data have been logged.
 */
void StatSampler::collect_sample() {
```

`WatcherThread` executes registered instances of `PeriodicTask` class, and [`StatSamplerTask`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a9b412abe617/src/share/vm/runtime/statSampler.cpp#l55) is one of such tasks.